# What is the swap file for?

Tags: windows-7, memory, swap

I don't get it why is that the more RAM memory you have, the larger the swap file is.
Shouldn't it be the other way around? I was under the impression that HDD space is used when there isn't enough RAM memory to satisfy the needs of the system and apps.

Comment: Are you asking what is the swap file for or why is it bigger the more memory you have? These are two different questions.

Comment: The swap or pagefile file is used to by the operating system to lie to applications.  The swap file is used by the operating system so that a given application can request a given amount of memory, be assigned virtual memory, and eventually be assigned the physical memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your understand is correct. The swap file size (or paging file) is just a default settings. Windows default the ratio to be approx ~ 1

Answer (score 1):

first off, for some sleep and hibernate states (depending on OS), you need to cache process memory to disk, so the size of the swap must be greater than or equal to the size of the ram it will cache, in case you were already full up.

More fundamentally however, the windows virtual memory system reserves the Private footprint for a processes' memory both in RAM and in Virtual memory at process load time, even if the process will never use any of the reserved footprint in the pagefile. Note that this space is reserved, not allocated. Also note that a process can specify an amount of private memory that it may not actually use, when making a reservation.

Heres a telling quote from the MSDN blogs about Memory usage in the page file:

> Why might/does the operating system allocate space in the swap file to hold the contents of memory whose contents have never become resident and may never become resident?  The answer is not actually so complicated:  Windows cannot deliver an "out of memory" exception/error just because you tried writing to, for instance, a static variable.  The swap space must be pre-allocated at a reasonable time (such as loading a DLL) so that we can deliver an error result at a reasonable time -- the time at which the virtual addresses changed from reserved to committed. 
>   [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/08/01/446329.aspx)

As an example, in Process Explorer the Private Bytes metric for process memory usage refers to the amount of the page file reserved for that process, which will be sufficient to store the process memory even if the process is completely paged out to disk. The Working Set metric shows the amount of physical ram being used by the program (plus any shared objects that the process may be utilizing).

see some more info here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/08/01/446329.aspx
- [Private Bytes VS Working Set in Process Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/618686/private-bytes-vs-working-set-in-process-explorer)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. RAM and swap space make up the entire virtual memory. OS'es have a tendency to use RAM to the fullest because it's faster. When you run out of RAM, the system will write unused memory pages to the pagefile.

Since the beginning of virtual memory there have been formulas regarding the amount of swap space you should reserve on disk, usually between 1x and 2x you RAM size. While this was true before, nowadays a desktop with 16G memory isn't going to need *any* swap space unless you start doing serious video editing or other memory-intensive applications. However, Windows still calculates swap space using a formula based on RAM and available disk space.

The best way to determine how large your swap should be is to check the amount of virtual memory used when you are using memory to the max. Then go 1 or 2G above that. As said, I can't think of many scenario's where a desktop with 16G of RAM would need any swap, and even for an 8G machine I highly doubt you would need any.

Comment: Sorry but "RAM and swap space make up the entire virtual memory" is not true. There is also virtual address space that is mapped to files. It is just as much "virtual memory" as that for which the pagefile is the backing store.