# Why is my private memory usage so low compared to commit memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-management

After 120 hours of stable uptime on a Windows 7 computer (with hibernates instead of restarts between days), Windows has done something strange: programs consume large amounts of memory as usual, but the private working set usage (which is what is reported by Task Manager) is *so low* compared to the actual memory committed.

Usually, the working set usage is about the same as the commit, but strangely not so here in Resource Monitor:

[image: Very low private usage, very high commit]

On these processes, the private working set consumption barely changes at all. It's as if Windows put these background processes on cryostasis.

Why is this happening? Is the prolonged uptime affecting the caching behavior?

Comment: I'm surprised that you usually see working set = commit, since they mean almost opposite things. Commit Charge refers to the amount of a process that is only in pagefile, whereas Working set only refers to data in RAM. it would be surprising for the split to be 50/50. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge  Personally, that you have 80% of RAM in use is a compelling explanation for why private working set is low, and commit is high. Commit should equal Private Bytes - Private Working Set. http://superuser.com/questions/618686/private-bytes-vs-working-set-in-process-explorer/618811#618811

Comment: Also remember, your RAM is completely moved to the page file and to hiberfil.sys upon hibernation, so if those processes haven't been active since a hibernation, it makes sense that the majority of their contents would be page file resident.

Comment: @FrankThomas Your assertion about commit charge is incorrect. Commit charge refers to the "private committed" virtual address space of a process - that is, v.a.s. for which the pagefile is the _backing store_. But that doesn't mean it's _all_ in the pagefile! We can say though that if everything in the process had to be paged out, that's how much pagefile space it would take. In normal circs typically some of it is nowhere (because it hasn't been touched yet and so hasn't been "faulted in"); some (esp. the most recently accessed subset) will be in RAM; and the rest in the pagefile.

Comment: Of course if you have no pagefile all of the committed, faulted-in v.a.s. is in RAM all the time. It's still called "commit charge".