# How to see real ram usage for each program in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, task-manager

when i press ctrl-alt-del and open Task manager I see that Memory is  used  at 80% (Performance tab), but if I add all the memory usage values for each program from the Processes tabs there's no way it adds up to 80% ! How can I see the real memory usage for each app?

PS: I found that view... select columns let's me show more data. So I checked all memory columns and the only one that could reach that 80% value is "Peak working set". There the values are much higher and I see a huge 2.5 GB usage from "svchost". But svchost is some kind of library, how can I see what program makes it use so much?

Here's a screenshot to see what I mean:

[image: Task Manager]

Total RAM is 8 GB and usage is always at 6 GB +

PPS:

closing virtualbox freed a lot of RAM, down to 50%, but why doesn't the virtualbox real ram usage show up in task manager?

Comment: I use Process Explorer from Microsoft. To measure ACTUAL usage of physical ram, look at the Private Working Set (aka WS Private) metric. you will have to add a column to see it in the main grid.
See my comments here for a description of what the different memory statuses measure: http://superuser.com/questions/618686/private-bytes-vs-working-set-in-process-explorer

Comment: Peak Working Set is the highest value used during the process lifetime. So it's most likely not what you're looking for.

Comment: is your question answered? Do you need more help?

Comment: Related to the original question: [RAM usage % on Task Manager lower than actual RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/1278009/ram-usage-on-task-manager-lower-than-actual-ram)

Answer (score 1):

The `svchost.exe` is a container to start Windows services. Windows 7 has a bug, which causes a large memory usage of the WindowsUpdate service. Microsoft fixed it in several Windows Update Client updates. Install the latest one from [December 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3112343) to fix the memory usage.

For a detailed memory usage overview, always use [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx).