# Windows Powershell Get-Process PrivateMemorySize > WorkingSet

Tags: windows-10, memory, powershell, task-manager

As of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170654/how-to-interpret-windows-task-manager) article references, WorkingSet should always be greater than PrivateWorkingSet. Running a quick lookup shows different result - [please refer the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgudW.png).

Script:

```
get-process chrome | select name, Id, @{l="Private Memory (KB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1kb}}, @{l="Working Set (KB)"; e={$_.WorkingSet / 1kb}}
```

Could anybody pass some light.

Comment: well, Greater than or equal to. if a program doesn't use any shared pages, then its WS and PWS are the same.

Comment: `PrivateMemorySize` is not private working set.

Comment: Take a look at this similar StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878927/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-display-the-ws-private-bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you understand the article correctly. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/618686/private-bytes-vs-working-set-in-process-explorer/618811) for more info on the difference between private bytes, working set, and private working set.

In your case, the problem is you are specifying `privatememorysize`.

Per MS, [PrivateMemorySize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the Private Bytes metric, not private working set.

Here is documentation for the [Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! To get Private Working Set refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878927/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-display-the-ws-private-bytes) or [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1)