# Why is RAM usage increasing continuously in GoDaddy VPS Win 2016

Tags: windows, memory, apache-http-server, godaddy

I have a .NET website hosted with GoDaddy VPS.

It's a Windows 2016 server and it is also running a SQL express instance and I'm using Plesk.
It also has mysql installed, which I think is used by Plesk.

Initially I chose a 2GB RAM server config, but it crashed twice and I noticed the RAM would start at about 1.5GB usage and continue to go up to 2GB and then the server would sort of crash.

I say sort of because I could still access MS-SQL, still RDP, but my website would not work and the Plesk dashboard would be down.

So I just upgraded to the 32GB of RAM server because the website is live and my client is paying me.

But since I upgraded a few weeks ago, the RAM is still growing slowly over time. It is now on about 40% usage, which is about 13GB of RAM!!

I am running 2 basic IIS websites. In Task Manager, there are 2 IIS processes, each using 175MB of RAM.
I also see SQL and DrWeb using about 450MB each. There is a DNS service and a non-sucking service manager using another 350MB of RAM. Besides that, there is nothing using more than 10-40MB of RAM, and if I add up all the processes, I get to about 2-3GB.

On the performance tab of task manager, it shows 7.8GB of cached committed memory. I don't know what that means, but I think that's where the RAM is going.

I am not a server admin but I do know the basics and I've checked many things.

I have other websites using GoDaddy's shared hosting and the websites are very similar (clones in fact), and none of them have issues like this, so I don't think it's my website.

I personally think it is related to GoDaddy's virtualisation software or whatever. The ugprade from a 2GB server to a 32GB server took 3 hours. That to me is a clear sign of something weird going on.

Whatever the cause, how I can go about to find what is causing the RAM increase over time??

I've read it's normal, but when it gets that high, my website crashes, so that can't be normal.

I've ran perfmon logs to save working memory, but I have no idea how to analyze that info as it is hundreds of lines and many different processes.

Some strange activity on the server I do see is that it runs various python/powershell/conhost scripts. They appear to use about 40MB of ram, then die, and then a new one starts. But they remain as greyed out in task manager, so i'm not sure if that is something to look into or not.

I just want to know what is going on, but i don't know enough about VM's and servers to know how to diagnose this problem.

I would appreciate any help. I'm willing to pay for help but I also don't know where to find this sort of service, if someone knows of not-too-expensive companies that can help with this that would be great too.

GoDaddy's support is utterly terrible. I've already tried their paid diagnosis and I honestly believe they just sit there for 1 hour and say it's my software and I need to contact my server admin.

---

I read that the page file size should be between 1.5 and 4 times the RAM. I plan on trying this soon. I have to wait for my client to approve because the server is live and the client depends on the server. Will update once that's done.

And that said, changing the page file size has done nothing for me. The RAM is still going up at about 1% every 9 hours. Very frustrating.

Below is the info using Process Explorer
[image]

Here is the performance tab of task manager:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

After many calls with GoDaddy and promises of a solution to my problem, all which have yielded nothing, my server spontaneously restarted a couple of weeks ago, after which the RAM remained very steady for almost a month, when all of a sudden it just started going up gradually again as per my original problem.

I don't think it's related to usage because the usage has been steady. I actually think the issue is not with my code, my program, SQL, or anything I have control over. I think it's related to the software running GoDaddy's VMs and the stuff they do.

Comment: I assume testing or using another VPS host isn’t an option?

Comment: I would have to carry that cost, but it is something I will try once I've exhausted other options

Comment: Try looking at the problem with [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) instead of task manager.  Right click on the columns header to add more items to watch.  Your answer as to who is leaking is there for the taking but you need to be able to narrow down your search.  BTW, with 32gb.. your page file shouldn't be hit much.  Some things don't work right without it but  a LARGER pagefile isn't the solution with 32gb of ram.

Comment: Thanks, i've launched process explorer but see more or less the same info as with task manager and resource monitor.
What should i be looking for here?

Comment: Launch Process Explorer, right-click on a column header and click "Select Columns". In the "Process Memory" tab, select "Private Bytes" and click OK. Click on the new column to order by size descending. This may help find the process that is leaking memory. ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/618686/private-bytes-vs-working-set-in-process-explorer))

Comment: this appears to be a problem with the latest versions of windows, a system process appears to have a memory leak. an easy way to fix this is to have a server restart once every 24 hours, figure out when your client's website has no traffic during the day, and make a scheduled restart then, it generally only takes 3-5 minutes.

Comment: Added a screenshot with private bytes. Only showing the top 20 or so processes, as I assume those are the main ones to look at.

Comment: Could you also add a screenshot of the performance tab of task manager?

Comment: @harrymc added.

Comment: I would think you have to look at process explorer twice. Once now and once again 24+ hours later. Then you can see what process seems to of grown by the amount of ram usage you see has changed. Also, is linux and option?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a memory leak.
First of all, download a program like Process Explorer 2 on to the VPS and search through ALL of the running processes while it is a super high memory and look for the one using the most. It could be a system process, like search indexing.

If it is **not** a system process and is NOT critical to your website, try to figure out what it is (comment here), and if you can disable it, do.

If it is a noncritical system process (like search indexing) and you don't need it, try disabling it and restarting.

If you 100% need it for your use OR it is a critical system process, then the easiest way is to do a restart (usually takes 3-5 minutes) once-twice every day during the time where the server gets little to no traffic. Ask GoDaddy about this and tell them something like:
"Could we set up a scheduled restart at 12am EST every day?"
and they will know exactly what you mean.

If you have any questions, let me know in a comment and I will respond as fast as possible.
Hope this helps!

Comment: My problem is the RAM usage goes up about 1% every 9 hours, and there is 32GB of RAM. So it'll take a couple of days or weeks to reach "very high" numbers. But I will try Process Explorer 2, but from what I can gather so far, it's more committed, or cached, RAM, rather than RAM being used by an active process that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better for comparison purposes to to add more and later screenshots
of the ones in your updates 3 & 4. If the crash caused was a Windows BSOD,
please also post the dump(s) in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`
(access requires administrator permission).

My understanding of the image you have shown is as follows.

- Your entire RAM is not fully used and Windows had no need yet to compress any
  memory. (See [Memory Compression](https://www.howtogeek.com/319933/what-is-memory-compression-in-windows-10/).)
- The sum-total of the memory of all programs is far from accounting for the used
  memory.

My conclusion is that the memory leak is not in any of the programs, but in Windows
itself. This can be in Microsoft software but also in a third-party driver.
The conclusion is also supported by the fact that it causes a crash, while a
user program would only be swapped out to disk and slow down, but wouldn't crash
Windows.

Since this is a production system, the advice I can give is very limited.
Advice like uninstalling all security software or using a
[clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
probably doesn't apply.

In all probability you should accept the situation and try to live with it.
You can create a scheduled task to reboot Windows and restart any required
software, for example once a week late at night when your client is not working.

Comment: I think i clearly stated the server crashes because the RAM reaches 100% usage, no BSOD or anything like that that i'm aware of.
The ram is not currently at 100% in the images, but it keeps going up until it gets there.

"Live with it" - that's not quite an acceptable solution for me or my clients.

Comment: no solution found yet. I will update when do find a solution.